# Has anyone created a MIPS syntax highlighter for Ace Editor?

Tags: user-interface, mips, ace-editor

I'm trying to create a MIPS syntax highlighting. There's a copy of the .tmLanguage file to be used for TextMate markup and the like on GitHub [here](https://github.com/textmate/mips.tmbundle/blob/master/Syntaxes/MIPS.tmLanguage).

I'm also aware that Ace Editor's ability to perform a conversion on this file. The setup did not seem nontrivial, and I ran into trouble when trying to do so.

Does anyone know of an existing solution for MIPS Assembly language syntax highlighting for Ace Editor?

If not, would anyone be able to generate the conversion file based of the tmLanguage and then I can take it from there, or enlighten me on how to setup the conversion tool properly? I had issues when doing so from the Ace site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run conversion tool you need to run

```
cd tool  
npm install
node tmlanguage.js https://raw.githubusercontent.com/textmate/mips.tmbundle/master/Syntaxes/MIPS.tmLanguage
```

it successfully creates the mode, but sets a wrong name in ext/mode_list, should be `MIPS_Assembler` instead of `MIPSAssembler`

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to go through and install Node.js tonight and do it. Hopefully the Ace conversion tool is able to successfully convert the doc, although I doubt it. Just thought I would put it out there and see if anyone has already perfected a MIPS version.